# Cannot match any routes: ''

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have a defined route in angular2 application and receive such error:

Cannot match any routes: ''

```js
export const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,

  children: [{
    path: 'callCenter',
    component: CallCenterComponent,
    resolve: {
      countries: CountriesResolver
    },
  }, {
    path: 'vehicle',
    component: VehicleComponent,
    resolve: {
      vehicleCategories: VehicleCategoryResolver,
      vehicleOptions: VehicleOptionResolver
    },
  }, {
    path: 'territory',
    component: TerritoryComponent,
    resolve: {
      territoryOptions: TerritoryOptionResolver
    }
  },{
    path: 'token',
    component: TokenGenerationComponent
  }, {
    path: 'rider',
    component: RiderComponent
  }, {
    path: 'dispatch',
    component: DispatchSchemaComponent,
    resolve: {
      dispatchOrders: DispatchOrderResolver,
      dispatchModes: DispatchModeResolver
    }
  }]
}, {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
}];
```

This is a code of my route config. I make it the same as in examples but it does not work, redirectTo property does not help also. default empty route does not loading. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe angular is expecting MainComponent child routes to have route with path ''.

```js
 export const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,

  children: [{
      path: '',
      component: SomeComponent
     },
     {
     path: 'callCenter',
     component: CallCenterComponent,
     resolve: {
      countries: CountriesResolver
    },
  }, {
    path: 'vehicle',
    component: VehicleComponent,
    resolve: {
      vehicleCategories: VehicleCategoryResolver,
      vehicleOptions: VehicleOptionResolver
    },
  }, {
    path: 'territory',
    component: TerritoryComponent,
    resolve: {
      territoryOptions: TerritoryOptionResolver
    }
  },{
    path: 'token',
    component: TokenGenerationComponent
  }, {
    path: 'rider',
    component: RiderComponent
  }, {
    path: 'dispatch',
    component: DispatchSchemaComponent,
    resolve: {
      dispatchOrders: DispatchOrderResolver,
      dispatchModes: DispatchModeResolver
    }
  }]
}, {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
}];
```

**Edit:**
With some redirecting

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'callCenter'
      },
      {
        path: 'callCenter',
        component: CallCenterComponent,
        resolve: {
          countries: CountriesResolver
        },
      }, {
        path: 'vehicle',
        component: VehicleComponent,
        resolve: {
          vehicleCategories: VehicleCategoryResolver,
          vehicleOptions: VehicleOptionResolver
        },
      }
    ...
```

Moving the MainComponent to child routes should also work

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'callCenter',
        component: CallCenterComponent,
        resolve: {
          countries: CountriesResolver
        },
      }, {
        path: 'vehicle',
        component: VehicleComponent,
        resolve: {
          vehicleCategories: VehicleCategoryResolver,
          vehicleOptions: VehicleOptionResolver
        },
      }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, can you please describe why it works in this way? Anf also If I do not want to use default component, can I use redirectTo here or some kind of mocked empty component?

Comment: I don't know why angular does it like this, maybe someone wiser can answer that. You can redirect to another route with redirectTo, i edited answer a little

Comment: Thank you a lot for a help, you save a lot of time for me, because this route is very different from usual ui-router from the first angular that I used to.