# Cannot match any routes angular 2.0.1

Tags: angular, router

I have a problem with my plunkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/70ZFRPJdAraDDV8heMlo?p=preview

```
const routes = [
    {path: 'test', component: Test},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: "full"}
];

this.router.navigate('/test');
```

I can't simply do a router.navigate. I have the error :

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 't/e/s/t'

Everything looks ok to me.
Related to [Cannot match any routes: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257402/cannot-match-any-routes) but I don't have any children routes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[]`

```
this.router.navigate(['/test']);
```

or use `navigateByUrl()`

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/test');
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dl1jnqwIRjrgiHZx1otM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

no slash before the path and brackets ...

```
this.router.navigate(['test']);
```